# Converting PDF to JPG with Imagemagick is really slow after update

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, centos, jpeg, ghostscript

I have several servers set up using Centos 5 (64bit) and the default yum installed versions of Ghostscript (v8.70) and Imagemagick (v6.2.8) which work really well and are very quick at converting PDF files into JPG previews.

I have removed both IM and GS on one of my servers and installed the latest versions Ghostscript(v9.0.7) and Imagemagick(v6.8.5) from source and the conversion speed has gone from around 0.5 seconds to 7.5 seconds for exactly the same original PDF.

I need to be able to run the later version of both to be able to use the inkcov device for working out which pages are colour in multipage pdfs (up to 200 pages).

Now I am assuming this slowdown is due to the compile options, as I can't believe that the later versions are so much slower. I have searched around to try and find ways of optimising at the compilation stage (changing to Q8 rather than Q16 quality etc) but nothing seems to make much difference.

thanks

Comment: You might have run into [this bug](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=14307&start=0). Try compiling with `--disable-openmp`.

Comment: Just given that a shot but it made no difference :/

Comment: Try downgrading just one component (ImageMagick or Ghostscript) to the previous version and try again. You should at least be able to eliminate one suspect.